# node.js authentication with sequelize and passport - promise and callback confusion

Tags: mongodb, promise, callback, sequelize.js, passport.js

Hopefully someone can help me solve what I am sure is a rookie mistake.

I am trying to adapt an authentication app originally based on mongodb, to work with sequelize\MSSQL  instead, but getting tied up in knots with trying to blend a callback-based working example with 
seqeulize's promised based approach.

Both MongoDb\Sequelize offer a findOne() method.

Original (working) code referencing MongoDb collection:

```
module.exports.getUserByUsername = function(username,callback){
  var query = {username: username};
  User.findOne(query,callback);

}
```

The callback in this case is from a separate calling module and is the standard verify password of passport.js's local-strategy.

Since the sequelize findOne() method expects a where clause I had hoped the following would be an out of the box solution:

```
module.exports.getUserByUsername = function(username,callback){
    var query = {where: {username: username}};
    User.findOne(query,callback);
                                              }
```

This outputs a functional query into the console.log, but the callback doesn't fire, so the page hangs.

Looking at the respective API docs it appears that sequelize findOne() is exclusively promise based whereas MongoDb findOne() returns a promise only if where a callback function is not passed to the findOne() method, otherwise flow is handed to the callback when one is provided as is the case with the working example.

I tried the following adaptation to work with a sequelize promise (and quite a number of permutations thereof calling the callback function within the .then() clause etc)., but all fail with a hanging page: :

```
module.exports.getUserByUsername = function(username,callback){
    var query = {where: {username: username}};
  return  User.findOne(query).then(user => {
                                      console.log(user.get({ plain: true })); 
                                       return user.dataValues;
                                       //callback(user.dataValues)     
                                              }).finally(() => {
                                                                console.log('done!')
                                                                });
                                                                 }
```

The console.log(user.get()) spools out the correct details showing the database query executed correctly returning the required user data, so I feel that I'm very near to finding the right syntax to delivering this back to the passport callback.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Add raw property to true like this, and you can get the user object

```
User.findOne({ where : {username:username}, raw: true}).then( user => {
  return user
})
```

Comment: Many thanks for the steer.  This option enables the user data to be immediately accessible.  I still get a hanging web page which I think is because the callback is not executing.

Comment: Thanks Yoga Altariz, that helped me get a step closer in that I can console.log the returned user data without the the need for the get() statement, and flow is handed back to the callback function.  The code still breaks because I'm fumbling the user data in the callback.  Now getting a

Comment: Many Thanks Yoga Altariz, that helped me get a step closer in that I can console.log the returned user data without the the need for the get() statement, and flow is being handed back to the callback function.  

The code still breaks because I'm fumbling the user data in the callback.  I'm now getting a unhandle rejection error because there is only one object (user) being passed to an anonymous callback function that is defined with two arguments (err,callback) so struggling to get the right syntax to make sure both are returned in the right place..right now the user is passed to err.

Comment: Glad to hear my answer can help you. I don't get it what your problem right now, maybe you can share the code

Comment: Sure and thanks again. What's the best way?  Would you want to see the complete code via Github or just the two blocks of functions?

Comment: Hi Yoga, just wanted to circle back and thank you for your help with this.  Problem was in the end to do with how I was structuring the calling function, and then how I was passing arguments to its callback, which needed me to explicitly set and pass an null error if successful or null user if an error was returned. Possibly this is not the best way, being verbose, but a least works :-)